# Improving the performance of a celeron machine

Tags: ssd, performance, ram

I got a machine running Ubuntu Mate 20.04. Unfortunately it has a crappy Celeron N2830 CPU. So the performance is sub-par.

I upgraded the machine the best I could. I installed 8Gb of RAM and a SSD with 480 gigas.

My question is: is it possible to somehow improve the performance of this machine by making use of the misspent RAM? The RAM usage never goes beyond 2Gb.

Comment: Seems to me like you've done all the hardware upgrades you can... Ubuntu Mate is really lightweight so you're on the right track there too... have you run all your updates? also what is your video card? have you installed drivers for it?

Comment: You could also try two other lightweight Ubuntu flavours, Lubuntu and Xubuntu. Then compare the performance of all three, and select the one, that you prefer. Please be aware, that Lubuntu works optimally (lean and fast), when you use LXQt applications, but it works with GTK applications too. -- It might also be worthwhile to try non-Ubuntu ultra-light linux distros, for example Puppy Linux and Tiny Core. See also [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2130640).

Comment: To add to the above, [here is a giant list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-weight_Linux_distribution) of light-weight Linux distros. You can sort by fields, if you'd like. Not all of them look like archaic OSes from the early 90s, some of them look good.

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte, screenfetch informs me that my video card is Intel Mesa DRI and neofetch informs Intel Atom processor Z36xx/Z37